# How do I extend Lookup Transformation Editor in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0, ssis, user-interface

I have created a transformation component, and basically it accepts data from a source, and will do very transformations before it can save the information in a database.

But, I want to map between the source columns and the database columns that are called up from my transformation component.

I would like it to look like the mapping in Lookup Transformation Editor.

How do I create an editor that will have the same functionality for mapping, so that it will allow a user to draw a line from a source column to a destination column.

I am using Sql Server 2008 and VS2008 for this project.

I realize I will need to create a custom UI for this component, replacing the Advanced Editor that comes up by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my wrapper for the DtsMappingSurfaceControl: http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/07/using-dtsmappingsurfacecontrol-in-your.html